# window.event javascript code does not work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, firefox

I have an markup

```
            <div id="uploadControl" class="fileUpload1">
                    <label for="uploadFile" id="labelId">Choose File</label>
                    <input class="upload" type="file" id="uploadFile" />
                </div>
```

javascript

```
        window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('uploadControl').onclick = function (event) {

        // process the event only for the original source 
        if (window.event.srcElement.id === 'uploadControl') {
            document.getElementById('labelId').click();
        }
        //prevent event propagation
        window.event.cancelBubble = true;
    };
}
```

I want to the label to fire a click event for the input File whenever the "upload control" div is clicked. 
The problem is.... this works on IE and chrome but on firefox i get the message 
  **"TypeError: window.event is undefined "** 
It seems like firefox doesnt support window.event code.
How can i make it work on firefox? please help

Comment: Why you are not using `event` from `function (event) {`?

Comment: i posted answer can you try that

Answer (score 1):

Firefox doesn't support `windows.event` object. Use these variables to store the value and it will work after that use your code:

```
var event = e || window.event
var assumed = (event.target || event.srcElement).id;
```

Comment: change last line to this `var assumed = (event.target || event.srcElement).id;`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

**Tested and 100% working**

You can Combine here [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)(element)

```
function postBackByObject(e,d) {
            var target = e.target || e.srcElement;     // Support IE6-8

            if (d.id == 'uploadControl') {

                document.getElementById('labelId').click();
            }
            target.cancelBubble = true;
        }


<div id="uploadControl" class="fileUpload1" 
 onclick="postBackByObject(event,this);">
<label for="uploadFile" id="labelId">Choose File</label>
<input class="upload" type="file" id="uploadFile" />
                </div>
```