# window.event.target is not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox

I am working in `angularjs application`.  To display unsaved changes by alert message, we've used `window.event.target. Everything works fine in all browsers but`Firefox`.  The`error`is`window.event is undefined`.  Have you faced this problem before? Do You have any suggestion to solve it?.  Please help us.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <body>
      <input value="click" type="button" onclick="call()" />
      <script>
        function call() {
          var targ;
          if (!e) var e = window.event;
          if (e.target) targ = e.target;
          else if (e.srcElement) targ = e.srcElement;
          if (targ.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
            targ = targ.parentNode;
        }
      </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295901/firefox-window-event-is-undefined-error and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813445/why-ff-says-that-window-event-is-undefined-call-function-with-added-event-list

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26915279/window-event-javascript-code-does-not-work-in-firefox and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813153/window-event-alternative-in-firefox

Comment: your provided function name is different from callback registered for onclick event...And to work in firefox first  parameter to event handler should be event object..

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Chrome the event parameter must defined in Firefox

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>

    <body>
  <input value="click" type="button" onclick="grabId(event)" />
  <script>
    function grabId(event) {
      var targ;
      if (!e) var e = event;
      if (e.target) targ = e.target;
      else if (e.srcElement) targ = e.srcElement;
      if (targ.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
        targ = targ.parentNode;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Unlike Chrome the event parameter must defined in Firefox.

Comment: Hi Omidam81, the code that you sent shows this error....TypeError: e is undefined

Comment: code updated, we must pass the event parameter in FF.

Comment: its working for this html, but we are using angularjs directive.  we cannot able to use event while calling the function.

Comment: use this: <input value="click" type="button" onclick="grabId($event)" />

Answer (score 0):

Following should work, you should pass event to function itself:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
   <script>
    function call(e) {
      var targ;
      if (e.target) targ = e.target;
      else if (e.srcElement) targ = e.srcElement;
      if (targ.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
        targ = targ.parentNode;
    }
  </script>
  <input value="click" type="button" onclick="call(e)" />

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi adnan kamili, error ReferenceError: e is not defined

Comment: @keepontrying check the update answer script is before the html

Comment: yes, it willl work if we do call(event),  without using event while calling the function we have to do.