# window.event not working on firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, events, event-handling

my javascript code works on ie, chrome and safari however it does not working on firefox. I checked the  possible solutions but non of them working. still firefox says window.event undefined.

Javascript

```
function OnChooseItem(type, id, src) {
            window.event.cancelBubble = true;
            if (selectedView == "TileView") {
                if (selectedItem != void (0)) {
                    selectedItem.className = "ExplorerItem";
                    selectedItem._selected = false;
                }

                var event = src || window.event
                selectedItem = (event.target || event.srcElement).value;
                top.frames["OptionCallbackFrame"].MakeCallback(type, id);
                while (selectedItem.parentPanel == void (0)) {
                    selectedItem = selectedItem.parentElement;
                }
                selectedItem._selected = true;
                selectedItem.className = "ExplorerItemHover";

            } else {
                if (selectedItem != void (0)) {
                    selectedItem.className = selectedItem.__className;
                }
                selectedItem = src;

                selectedItem.className = "DataGridItemMarked";
                top.frames["OptionCallbackFrame"].MakeCallback(type, id);
            }
```

Server-Side

```
 panel.Attributes.Add("onclick", "OnChooseItem(" + Numbers.GetSafeValue(dataReader["TYPE"]) + ", '" + Strings.GetSafeValue(dataReader["DOCUMENT_ID"]) + "', this)");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox "window.event is undefined" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295901/firefox-window-event-is-undefined-error)

Comment: You literally copy paste your header into google: We got this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295901/firefox-window-event-is-undefined-error and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813153/window-event-alternative-in-firefox oh and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26915279/window-event-javascript-code-does-not-work-in-firefox should we continue...

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the event using the parameter passed:

```
var aVar = {
  anExample: function(event){ 
    var evnt = event || window.event    
  }
}
```